# Кавычки: даёшь «ёлочки»!

Tags: предложение

Когда открылся сайт для программистов [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), где прямые кавычки (`"` `"`) преобразовывались в английские (`“` `”`), я промолчал. Но сейчас, когда на сайте по русскому языку для русскоговорящих вовсю используются английские кавычки, я больше молчать не могу.

Даёшь [ёлочки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8) (`«` `»`)!

P.S. Кстати, этот призыв верен и для SOru, хоть там это и менее важно.

Comment: Во-первых, это не похоже на вопрос. Во-вторых, стоило бы в этом тексте научить людей ставить «ёлочки» в местной разметке каким-то удобным образом.

Comment: @AndreyRegentov Это не вопрос, это **feature request**. И он про то, чтобы расстановку ёлочек добавили в движок, а не про то, как вставлять символы в текст вручную.

Comment: @AndreyRegentov: вот инструкция: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498/181472

Comment: @М_Г а нужна ли здесь [поддержка]? Из описания метки: *"Метка для вопроса, описывающего затруднения при использовании каких-то возможностей сайта."*. Какие тут затруднения с использованием сайта? Как [дефект] уж тогда стоило бы пометить в паре с [локализация].

Comment: @älёxölüt Формально это запрос на изменения в сайте. Фактически я нашел в комментах ссылку с кодами этих самых елочек и теперь могу их добавлять самостоятельно (ALT-0171)  (ALT-0187). Для меня это поддержка.

Comment: @М_Г я считаю, что содержание ответа (а комментариев и подавно) не должно изменять вопрос. Есть исключения с красными модераторскими метками типа [статус-завершено] и пр., но это не тот случай. Иначе можно попасть в бесконечный цикл: правка ответа - правка вопроса ... Такого быть не должно.

Comment: @älёxölüt up to you