# Как использовать в тексте специальные символы: кавычки, тире, диакритические знаки?

Tags: поддержка, faq

На сайте, посвященном русскому языку, особенно важно писать грамотно, соблюдая все нормы русского языка. (Кстати, правки этого вопроса всячески приветствуются).

Часть этих норм предполагает использование знаков пунктуации, которых нет на обычной клавиатуре. Использовать их в вопросах и ответах довольно сложно.

Например, в русском языке принято использование [французских кавычек](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/177015) - «ёлочек», а [во вложении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/493/181472) - «немецких „лапок“».

В качестве дефиса принято использовать знак  «дефис-минус» (`-`), тире — знак «длинное тире» (`—`). Очень часто вместо тире используются два минуса подряд: `--`. В некоторых шрифтах они сливаются и выглядят похоже на тире, но далеко не во всех. Они правда разные, посмотрите:

```
-  минус-дефис
—  тире
```

Далее, часть вопросов может касаться постановки ударения. Как использовать такие замечательные символы как `á`, `é` и прочие?

Как использовать [знаки транскрипции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82) и [комбинируемые диакри̵̱̇́̈̄̋̊̀̉тические з͓наки](http://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/combining-diacritical-marks/)?

## Запрашивайте необходимые символы в комментариях к вопросу, я буду их добавлять.

Comment: На русском эти символы по большей части не нужны. Кроме разве ударения, хотя и без него прекрасно обходимся. А уж навязывать их авторам...

Comment: Дефис не является знаком препинания, это орфографический знак. Исправить бы.

Comment: @Tagirix: о, я и забыл об этом тексте. Здесь есть фактологическая ошибка, кстати.

Comment: @Tagirix: а вы не можете предложить правку, да?

Comment: У меня эта кнопка («править») неактивна. Только на Мете так.

Comment: @Tagirix: да, кажется до 1000 репутации нельзя править на Мете чужие сообщения. К сожалению, пока у меня нет времени переработать текст.

Comment: Нет необходимости в полном изменении текста, здесь только слово надо исправить. =)

Comment: @Tagirix: на самом деле правильный знак это `-`, а не `–`. Подробнее тут: [Коллективный перевод сайта сообществом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150)

Comment: По ссылке таблица с гласными звуками, вот эти символы на сайте не помешали бы. http://www.rsu.edu.ru/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/e-learning/Tihomirova_Phonetic/40.html

Comment: точно нужен способ ввода правильных кавычек и тире(эллипсиса), многие платформы не позволяют их ввести с клавиатуры

Comment: @Swift многие? Только в Windows с этим проблемы, насколько я знаю.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin ну вообще-то Windows  b OS X как раз позволяет, как бы. C альт-кодами правда беда. И с устройствами без клавитур

Comment: @Swift: поставьте типографскую раскладку Ильи Бирмана, все нужные символы должны быть под рукой. http://ilyabirman.ru/projects/typography-layout/

Answer (score 6):

## Windows

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Изображение: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code#/media/File:QWERTY_keyboard_alt_code_161_demonstration.gif), [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)

Используем [Alt-код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-%EA%EE%E4). Включить Num Lock, набирать на цифровой клавиатуре

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0171</kbd> = `«`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0187</kbd> = `»`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0132</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0147</kbd> = `“`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0150</kbd> = `–` (дефис)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0151</kbd> = `—` (тире)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0180</kbd> = `´` (ударение)

К сожалению, это ударение не ставится строго над буквой и разбивает слово на части:

> приве´т, ми´р!

Есть еще одно ударение, символ Юникода `U+0301 Combining Acute Accent`: `́`

Оно выглядит гораздо лучше, но его придется вставлять через таблицу символов:

> приве́т, ми́р!

Comment: Альт-коды не работают в браузере с редактором SE, они привязаны к командам навигации, например , альт-4 - назад.

Comment: Было бы хорошо, если их можно было бы вводить в формате &#0x0301 или \u0x0301

Comment: А для Linux нет?(

Answer (score 4):

## OS X

### Тире и дефис:

- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> = `–` (дефис)
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> = `—` (тире)´

### Кавычки

Раскладки «U.S»., «British»:

- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> = `«`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> = `»`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> = `“`

Раскладка «Russian»

- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> = `«`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> = `»`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> = `“`

Раскладка «Russian - PC»

- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> = `«`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> = `»`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>Щ</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Х</kbd> = `“`

### Диакритические знаки

Символы латиницы с диакритическими знаками набираются крайне просто: зажимаете кнопку соответствующей гласной и через секунду появляется список для выбора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С добавлением диакритических знаков к символам кириллицы немного сложнее. Нам понадобится раскладка US-extended. Набираем диакритический знак после буквы.

- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> = `á` (ударение)
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> = `ā` (горизонтальная черта, долгий звук)