# Как вставить в текст специальные символы, пользуясь мобильными приложениями?

Tags: обсуждение

Как вставить в текст специальные символы, пользуясь мобильными приложениями?
В продолжение вопроса 
[Как использовать в тексте специальные символы: кавычки, тире, диакритические знаки?](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0)

и в связи с комментарием Романа Бабаева (@РоманБабаев) к вопросу [Проверьте пунктуацию](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444299/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e/444302?noredirect=1#comment453230_444302)

Comment: *(Ничего, что я комментирую вопрос годовалой давности?)* Вопрос ещё актуален?